# Itext.Sharp Document to byte array problme

Tags: asp.net-mvc, itext

I have the following code:

```
public byte[] ExportToPdf(DataTable dt)
{
    iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();

    document.Open();
    iTextSharp.text.Font font5 = iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 5);

    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dt.Columns.Count);
    PdfPRow row = null;
    float[] widths = new float[] { 4f, 4f, 4f, 4f, 4f, 4f, 4f, 4f };

    table.SetWidths(widths);

    table.WidthPercentage = 100;

    foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
    {
        table.AddCell(new Phrase(c.ColumnName, font5));
    }

    document.Add(table);
    document.Close();

    byte[] bytes;
    MemoryStream msPDFData = new MemoryStream();
    PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, msPDFData);

    return msPDFData.ToArray();
}
```

And in another function i call the function like this:

```
byte[] bytes = ExportToPdf(table);
return File(bytes, "application/pdf", "RaportDocumenteEmise.pdf");
```

When i try to open the pdf it says that is damaged.
Somehow the byte array is empty.
Can say me what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Actually the PdfWriter should be instantiated even before the document is opened.

Comment: Your "solution" is wrong, please remove the comment. See my answer for the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
iTextSharp.text.Document document = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
document.Open();
```

A PDF is created using 5 simple steps:

1. Create a `Document` object
2. Create a `PdfWriter` instance
3. Open the document
4. Add content
5. Close the document

You don't have step 2. In your comment, you say that you've solved the problem by creating that instance *after* opening the document, but that's wrong! You need to create the `PdfWriter` instance *before* opening the document.

Opening the document writes the PDF header to the `OutputStream`. That can't happen without a valid `PdfWriter` instance.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing as you.
After many tries, I discovered that if I put `PdfWriter.GetInstance`
inside `using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) { }` everything works alright!

My full code is:

```
    public FileContentResult GetPDF() {
        string htmlContent = "<p>First line</p><p>Second line</p>";
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(htmlContent);
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);
        HTMLWorker hw= new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

        FileContentResult result;
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, ms);
            pdfDoc.Open();
            hw.Parse(sr);
            pdfDoc.Close();
            result = this.File(ms.ToArray(), "application/pdf", "teste.pdf");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Ps.: This is a method inside my Controller.